# perl: get a new file descriptor to redirect stdin to

Tags: perl, stdin

```
        my $EXE = FileHandle->new;
        my $fd = 3; # <-------- doest work
        open $EXE, q{-|},
            "$myexe make 2>&1 <%=$fd"
            or die('Cannot open EXE');
        $err = !(close $EXE);
```

I would like to redirect stdin to some dummy file descriptor (preferably not having to open a file).

Any suggestions how do i do it after `2>&1` to redirect stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2>&1    # Dups fd 1 onto fd 2
```

So

```
0<&3    # Dups fd 3 onto fd 0
<&3     # "<" affects fd 0 by default
```

So

```
open(my $from_child, '-|', "foo 2>&1 <&$fd")
```

I can't help wonder why you want to do this. Is it part of something that could be done better using [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run)?

Comment: yeah i get. 3: Bad file descriptor error. hmm i dont know much about IPC::Run.

Comment: What's a dummy fd? One that doesn't exist? Why do you expect to be able to read from something that doesn't exist?

Comment: i want to create a fd. how do i do that?

Comment: File descriptors are file handles. There are many ways to open file handles.

Comment: The problem i am facing is that... i cant just open a file and use that (it works) but sometimes my program could be in a dir where i cant write a file. is there something i can create on the fly like python's os.pipe()

Comment: `pipe`? That's really low level. `open '-|'` and `open '|-'` also create pipes. Again, pretty sure you want IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run. [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I tried: my $BRIN = FileHandle->new;
my $fd = fileno($BRIN); but that doesnt give me valid fileno

Comment: You gotta pass arguments to `->new()` or call `->open()` to actually open a handle. Anyway, don't use FileHandle. Just a lame wrapper for IO::File, which is just a lame wrapper for `open`.

Comment: You ask questions, but ignore the answers. `FileHandle->new` is not `pipe`.

Comment: Oh you said there are my ways to open file handles so I assume thats all needed

Comment: I am kinda hesitant to use ipc at the moment. Maybe in the future. I just wsnt to get it working with open and redirect stdin for now

Comment: Again, `FileHandle->new` doesn't open a file handle.

Comment: `</dev/null` would actually match what you said you needed.

Comment: just one quick since i work in many architecture. is it possible for a certain file system to not have /dev/null? if so, ill prob have to catch for it

Comment: @ealeon I'm not sure if there are operating systems with no null device, but it certainly won't always be in `/dev/null`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device